# No explanation for rep drop. Is this a feature or a bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I've seen a 55 points drop on Stack Overflow, and this is what the explanation looks like:

[image: screenshot]

(There is nothing visible below the "2 events" line.)

Is this a bug?

Comment: Weird. If I sort by time, the event shows as "removed", which is also weird because I'm *pretty* sure I'm not supposed to see that on someone else's profile. Did you try checking the "show removed posts" checkbox?

Comment: @lunboks it's a very recent change - it used to show "unupvote" and link to the post where the upvote was removed due to user being removed.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Oh wait, **user** removed. I thought it was a post. That's a bit stupid, calling both the events for post deletion and user deletion the same.

Comment: @lunboks hover the text as Bolt show in the answer and it's clear - "user was removed". It replaced the cryptic and wrong "unupvote" event..

Comment: @lunboks, ShaDowWizArd: It's also "removed" for posts but the tooltip will say "question was removed" or "answer was removed".

Comment: Ah this is a grouping error of some sort...will fix.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Sort reputation events by time
2. [Mouse over the word "removed" which now shows next to your rep loss](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GuideDangIt)
3. Tooltip says:

   [image: user was removed]

So somebody who upvoted and accepted your answers had had their account removed, and thus their votes were removed from your posts as well. That would explain the rep loss.

I'm not sure why in the post sort it says 2 events as opposed to just 1, or why it doesn't display anything at all. Chances are that it's a bug as you have indicated in your question.

Comment: unupvote and unaccept - two events. :)

Comment: One upvote only awards 10 rep max... there would have to be more than one unupvote and/or more than one unaccept for it to add up.

Comment: There was very recent change (yesterday?) as it used to show what post exactly was affected - it doesn't show anymore.

Comment: Removed votes because of a user deletion? Special circumstances aside, that's like throwing away a country's precious metal investments because they went under. Gold is still gold, and if you've earned it it makes little sense to discard it (and more infuriating to have your 'government' take it from you).

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: [Agreed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted)

Comment: Ok this explains a bit. Still what is shown is IMO pretty cryptic. I also think that the fact a user decided or was forced to close his/her/its account should have no effect on past votes (unless of course they're not genuine and are instead part of a cheating scheme).

Answer (score 6):

This happened because **two** users were removed.  It's not not intuitive at all (in several behavioral ways) to roll these up, so starting with the next build they'll be listed separately.  You'll see `n` separate events, both in the post and time sorts.