# Losing points for 'User was removed'

Tags: support, reputation, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “user was removed” mean and why did I lose 5 reputation for it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-i-lose-5-reputation-for-it)

I just lost ten points, and this was the only reason given.

Just wanted clarification really - what does it actually mean ?

To clarify, I lost 10 points from my main stackoverflow account, same name as this one.

Comment: huh? Is there an SO question to go with it?

Comment: @PeeHaa No there isn't; that's why I'm asking here. It just shows -10 User was removed in my reputation score, I searched and couldn't see what this means to sI thought it would be best to ask here. Unsure why this deserves a downvote.

Comment: Thanks tim, I searched for 'user was removed' and that did not show up; try it for yourself!  Anyway it explains the reason so all is good. I might ask though, why does my reputation get affected when someone removes their account, or their account is deleted through some punitive action - Does that affect the fact that my answer was considered to be valuable ?

Comment: To my mind it goes against the concepts that S/O are trying to exemplify; My reputation is an example to the sites consumers that my answers are helpful and useful, my answers to questions are voted up so enforce that usefulness. Removing from my reputation in this manner (and I assume removing the +votes against my answer in whatever question it was) seems to be detrimental to enforcement. Although I concede that it is useful in cases where someone has faked an account simply to bolster anothers reputation.

Comment: Related to your concerns, you may be interested in [the feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) that's linked in the answer to that duplicate. I'm unclear on what the specific reason for the current behaviour is, though.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your candor.