# Add "what's this?" links to "user was removed" and "serial upvoting" in reputation history

Tags: feature-request, serial-voting, deleted-accounts, reputation-history, help

Another day, [another user confused by one of these contextless messages](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/why-have-i-had-reputation-removed-for-serial-upvoting). Losing rep is scary and without a good explanation these users end up both confused and asking yet another duplicate question on Meta.

How about we add a little "what's this?" in the form of a superscript question mark (<sup>?</sup>) or question mark icon linking to some proper description of what these mean? (or hovertext or make the words a link, *something*). The serial voting one in particular seems to often be read as implicating the user, which is never fun.

Additionally the "User was removed" and "serial Xvoting" descriptions are plain text, unlike normal rep changes are links. Most rep changes give a quick link to where the change happened, but these more unusual ones don't.

Comment: Hmm, this reminds me of a design bug on Arqade... But anyway, good call on the unobtrusive help icon, since this information is pretty much only useful once.

Comment: A step further from this [Link here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130122/more-descriptive-user-was-removed-explanation/141373#141373). Totally approve.

Comment: You mean like in [this mockup for closed question formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBTRH.png)? (image from [I propose changing the term "closed" out for... something else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70061/i-propose-changing-the-term-closed-out-for-something-else))

Comment: @PopularDemand I've always thought the fully written out "what's this" was a bit excessive for things you're going to see often. A link and a question mark is pretty standard

Comment: Fair enough. But that same general idea? I'm not complaining here, just trying to make sure I understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: @PopularDemand yeah, something like that, or even just a tooltip explaining something

Answer (score 4):

This was done a while back (not sure exactly when).  An entry for "user was removed" links to [this help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed) and a voting-reversal entry links to [this help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed).

Because these events, unlike most rep changes, come from a group of posts and not just one, it's probably not practical to link to the specific questions and answers whose votes changed.  I've seen four-digit rep changes for these reasons; that'd be an *awful* lot of entries to enumerate under an expander-triangle.  It can be frustrating to not know where the hits came, but at least now you get an explanation.