# Why was I downvoted -10 - system shows: "USER REMOVED"?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-history

I can understand being downvoted because an answer is not relevant or helpful to a topic..

But, I logged in this afternoon, and see that I downvoted -10 and see in the list of actions, it was because USER REMOVED.

And I do see the post:
[What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

Which is because the user has been removed because of their choice, kicked out, etc.  However, I also see the user in the reference URL was downvoted -5 and I was downvoted -10..

Thanks for listening.

Comment: It's not a downvote. Read the linked post again.

Comment: Perhaps you should upvote the feature request [More descriptive “User was removed” explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130122/more-descriptive-user-was-removed-explanation)

Answer (score -2):

A user which had upvoted either two of your questions or one of your answers was removed (deleted by a moderator).

This can happen either because the user was demonstrating bad behavior, and was nuked out of orbit by a mod, or if the user requested that their account be deleted from the site.

Comment: Sorry but no point repeating the answer of the duplicate here.