# Reputation deducted by 5, comment says removed

Tags: support, reputation, negative-rep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “user was removed” mean and why did I lose 5 reputation for it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-i-lose-5-reputation-for-it)

I see a change in reputation that says "removed"and the reputation changed from 808 to 803.
That's a -5 change, is there any way of knowing what is this change for?

Comment: hover over the text

Comment: @lunboks Hovering over the text did not provide any more information than the comment itself. However Daniel's response below helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A user who upvoted one of your questions was removed¹ and his votes went with him.

¹ The removal of the account may have been at the user's request, or against his will. Only employees and perhaps moderators can tell.

Comment: Ohh now it makes sense. Thanks clarified my doubt.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter No, unupvote is for when a user retracts an upvote. This is "User was removed", in other words, account deleted.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter "removed" also shows up for deleted accounts, check http://stackoverflow.com/users/326439/ayusman?tab=reputation, it says "removed" in the middle column and "User was removed" in the right.

Comment: @DanielFischer never mind I'm an idiot. So much for being helpful