# Was downvoted by -20 and I see "User was removed"

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

Today I was downvoted by some user, but when I try to find what was the question on which I was downvoted, I see this message: "-20 User was removed"

Was the user a spam user who downvoted me multiple times and was removed by SO? Will I get -20 back if it was a spam?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it :)

Comment: As Oded said, you lost it because someone up-voted your answer, but your answer was removed because the question was removed because the user was removed. The person who up-voted your answer may or may not have been the user that was removed. Even if they *were* the removed user, it’s not necessarily because they were bad; they may have simply chosen to delete their account.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got it backwards.

A user who upvoted some of your posts in the past was removed from the site and the reputation they gave you was removed with the account.

Comment: Ouch! That hurts...

Comment: @Holf - Consider that some deleted users are sock puppets (not implying this is the case with the OP).

Comment: Haha, to be clear, I didn't create users to upvote me :P

Comment: @zengr - Wasn't trying to imply so, but to explain to Holf that though it is painful, sometimes the pain is self inflicted ;)

Comment: @Oded - Absolutely agree, it needs to be kept in check. Some might even go to the lengths of posting 'Ouch! That hurts...' in their devious desire to appear legitimate and play the system. Mwah-ha-ha-ha!