# Reputation history shows "-10 user was removed". Why was the user removed?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

Reputation history shows

[image]

Just curious to know why the user was removed. My guess is he down voted 5 of my answers. Is that the reason?

Comment: Opposite of that: A user who upvoted one of your answers was deleted. (maybe not one answer, but at least a net +10 in rep of votes)

Comment: but it did not affect my reputation..

Comment: That user upvoted one of your questions, and thereby added 10 to your total reputation, before being deleted. The net effect on you was +10-10 = 0. It may have had nothing at all to do with you - maybe they actually *asked* to be removed.

Comment: Information about the reason for removal of users is not made public.