# Mean of Reputation Entry User was removed

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

I just noticed in my Reputation the notation `User was removed` and a loss of 5 reputation points.

What does that mean?

Comment: Means the user was deleted and their votes went with them; happens because of spam users (rare, they don't vote often) or users that requested deletion (rare, but more likely)