# User was removed need to show which answer/question loses its reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, deleted-accounts, lost-reputation

Lose some reputation from stack with showing **User was removed**. At least please show us which answer/question loses its reputation?

No hint for reputation lost is shown.

Comment: @Lucifer not sure about that, deleted users profiles show only a 404 page even to ♦ mods :)

Comment: @Rory okey.....:)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how this could be implemented neatly - `User was removed` shows a **summary** of reputation lost.  I suppose that it could be broken down into **individual** entries, however in the rare cases that someone had legitimately voted for you many times this could rather clog your reputation history!

Plus, I also don't see what is really gained by being able to see which posts lost votes?  Why does it matter?

As [Flexo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153020/flexo) pointed out in comments, this would also undermine the anonymity of voting.  I don't see that sufficient advantage is gained by showing this information to offset this problem.

Comment: Showing details of this would break the "voting is anonymous" thing quite substantially I think, above and beyond the clutter factor.

Comment: It was my personal opinion. If we gain something, we will not go into deep, how it was gained. But if we lost something, we will go into deep and have lots of question, why it was lost?

Comment: So, how will we get the lost reputation? I want to know why I recieve something like that and which question?

Comment: You received the message because a user either asked that their account was deleted or was deleted due to abuse.  [See this faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

Comment: Ok, I read the faq that you posted. Then how can I regain my reputation again so I could ask question? Yesterday, I recieve the above "downvotes", today I gain 15 upvotes but I can't still ask questions.

Comment: Are you getting "[Sorry we are no longer accepting questions from this account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)"?  These two messages are not related.

Comment: Yes, I do receive it. I think this is due to the downvote that I receive yesterday cause by the User is Removed.

Comment: Although I agree that exposing the full details of the user might be breaching privacy as @Flexo noted... as a curious person (like most developers I know ;-) I'd like to have a bit more insight into the "why". E.g. I doubt many users request to have their account pulled but I can see where a user gets "banned" for some reason. Even losing 10 points "hurts"... it would be nice to know a bit more. e.g. "A bot user was detected and removed (including votes cast)" or similar based on whatever the reasoning is.

Comment: @scu we do record some more details about why accounts were deleted now, but I'm not sure "TOS violation" or spam/nonsense really adds any information to the reputation event.