# Accurate accounting for lost rep after "User was removed"

Tags: support, reputation

I have read the other threads about "User was removed", in particular [what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it) but I'm not sure this was addressed anywhere in detail:

I would appreciate if someone could give an accurate account of everything I may lose (or win) after someone's account has been removed.

A couple days ago, I answered three questions from a rather feisty user. After her account was deleted today, I am under the impression that I lost more than just the points she had awarded me. Including:

- the rep points from other users' up-votes on my answers to the removed user's questions (please confirm)
- in my summary, it looks as if I never answered her three questions

Anything else? Thank you.

Comment: is your answer count decreased by 3 ?

Comment: @Lucifer - truly ridiculous editing. You are changing content and writing style *why*? Because you don't like the contraction 'I'm"? **Geez**

Comment: I agree, this is insane.  "User was removed" - thats it?  Everything else is detailed to the Nth degree but for some has-to-be-interesting-reason, "User was removed" is all we're told?  We cant even know the question(s)/answer(s)?   The user(s)?  Nothing else?  Just "User was removed".  Wow.  Talk about raising red flags.......

Comment: I love that after a year, this is still happening. Come on Stack, one of the biggest tech forums on the net should not penalise it's active community because of users being removed.