# What is "user was removed" message with down reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

I see in my reputation log a line, which says

```
-5  1 hour ago  removed     User was removed
```

What does this mean? I haven't remove any users! :)

Answer (score 8):

A user upvoted one of your questions; but that user has since been removed/deleted. Therefore, your reputation from that upvote has been removed as well.

Answer (score 5):

It means a user's account was deleted (for a serious breach of the rules or a request for self deletion). This meant that any votes they cast were removed from the system. You had received an upvote on one of your questions from this user. Removing this vote gives you -5 points.

Comment: The reason also might have been requested self-deletion

Comment: @MadScientist - good point. I shouldn't always see the bad side.