# "User was removed" I lost 2 rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I looked at [my reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305911/jnf?tab=reputation) and saw that I lost -2 rep with the explanation `User was removed`. I searched around and found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it).

But then, something doesn't fit in. According to [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) up-votes of any kind can give me rep by multiples of 5 - but I lost 2 rep. How?

Comment: Probably you edited some post and the post associated with that user is also removed? Some other (far-fetched) possibilities are you are upvoted to question once and you downvote that user 3 times, OR you got upvote to question once and you downvote that user once and that user downvote you once.

Comment: What @nhahtdh said, when a post you had suggested an edit on is deleted, you lose the rep for it. Typically posts aren't deleted when an account is deleted, but it happens on occasion.

Comment: @nhahtdh, right. Missed the 'edit' part.

Comment: Look man, an upside down 5 is just a 2.  2+5=7. And 7 is a magic number. 6 is the number in half a dozen donuts. So clearly, buy a donut, then things will be better.

Comment: @jonsca Uhh.. just chuck it. Anyway the question is closed.

Comment: @YatharthROCK I fixed it and accepted it, no worries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the possibilities I can think of:-

- You accepted an answer but the posts owner got deleted and so did his/her posts (which is rare, normally ownership is transferred to [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)), rolling back your +2 rep;
- You edited a post and the OP's account was deleted, rolling back your +2 rep (thanks to [@nhahdth's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149845/user-was-removed-i-lost-2-rep/149846#comment431027_149845);
- A user who had upvoted 1 answer or 2 questions and downvoted 4 posts (i.e., questions or answers) had his account deleted (see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YatharthROCK/jSSUF/) to calculate more combinations);

Comment: Correct on #2, a suggested edit approval was the cause here.

Comment: @NickCraver Oh... but what;s the justification behind it? The user contributed good and deserved his 2 rep, didn't he? Just b'coz you have no use of his/her edits, doesn't mean you take back your 2 rep. And why are the posts of a deleted user also deleted? Why not just transferred to Community? Sorry if I'm rude, but just my 2c...

Comment: Posts by a user are *not* typically deleted, that's a special button for spam users.  Votes *by* the user are deleted, since many delete cases are sock puppet gaming.

Comment: @NickCraver I looked at JNF's rep history and the only time his rep was lost due to a user being removed was on Aug 5 and he lost _5_ rep, not _2_. WTH is going on here?

Comment: He's actually talking about his Stack Overflow (**not** meta) profile, it's a bad link in the question.

Comment: @NickCraver That was me. Fixed it now.