# Reopen meta question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, meta, reopen-closed

I don't think I actually ever wanted to vote to reopen a question posted on meta until today.

I have had a -2 in my reputation history and wondered where it came from. Went to meta and found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149845/user-was-removed-i-lost-2-rep) which was somehow helpful.

The first sentence of the close reason

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors;

is not true as it has helped me and possibly 3 other people who voted up the question.

So I need a [3K rep points here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to cast a re-open vote but I'd like to know if any of you agree that the question shouldn't be closed as *too localized(which in fact is not a valid close reason any longer).*

Comment: Why would it need to be open? Is there something you wish to contribute?

Comment: @Bart If the question is legitamate it should be open in case someone else has a better answer

Comment: not necessarily myself. But valid questions shouldn't be closed?

Comment: @Bart I guess it's because close reason makes too little sense. I'd rather see this question re-closed as a dupe of ["How does reputation work"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) than showing readers hard to believe statement that it's _is unlikely to help any future visitors_

Comment: It should be closed as dupe of [this faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/152859) - I flagged it asking to do this. No point leaving it open as the faq contains all answers and if not, they should be added in there.

Comment: Myeah, kinda my point. You'd end up closing it again anyway. But well, it might have a more useful message then.

Comment: It's still a localized and/or a duplicate of [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/187824) IMO. Do I need to ask another question if I lose 4 reputation for "User was removed"?

Comment: One question to be asked here is that, is it really that necessary to re-open a question, just to close it again with another reason?! Can't we involve a mod here to do this instead of 5 people casting a reopen vote and then 5 people casting a close vote again?

Comment: Yea so updating FAQ wouldnt be a bad idea explaining the -2. Since upvote on a question is 5 and answer 10 the -2 is throwing me off a bit. But yeah @R.J youve got a valid point

Comment: Why would the FAQ need to be updated? We have a question explaining how you can get rep, and one explaining how you can lose it again if a user is removed. What information is missing between those two?

Comment: @Bart since I came to meta to research the -2 and found a matching question in the search result query on the first page it means that information is needed to be outlined somewhere is the question is to be left closed

Comment: We could take the shortcut and delete it. That would save us the reopen/close again part.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby It is true, duplicates are worthless and are autodeleted anyway. Specific duplicates that link to a more general FAQ are even more worthless because people don't actual search for the problems they have

Comment: @RichardTingle FWIW last time I checked, [duplicates aren't auto-deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773)

Comment: @gnat There was perhaps a small quantity of sarcasm in my comment

Comment: @RichardTingle you should add unicorns (or at least smileys ;)) to help us understand sarcasm is involved. :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've reopened the question and closed it again as a duplicate of the relevant FAQ.

Comment: Not what the OP here originally wanted, but the correct action in my opinion. :)

Comment: By the way, the question had a pending delete vote - what happened to it? As far as I can remember reopen won't clear delete votes.

Comment: @ShaWiz I didn't think they did either, but apparently now reopening clears them. This is the second time I've seen this happen.

Comment: Weird... bug report is due? :)