# -2 19 mins ago - removed - User was removed . But How -2?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-accounts

I know that if a user is removed, all his votes will be cancelled. So some users may have negative reputation changes as a multiple of `10` or `5`. But How `-2` reputation change for user removal?  I got this message few minuets before. Any idea? 
[image]

Comment: I've retracted my close vote, but is there any value at all in a question that's just resulting in maths guesses?

Comment: Its a [support] question. Not all support queries carry value. The only value I see in this question is that it is educating one more community member.

Comment: Note that votes come in different sizes. You can receive -2 when someone downvotes you, you can be reputation capped an a vote then only counts for the remainder between your total from up and downvotes and 200 points. As a result the total reputation change from a users votes is not necessarily a multiple of 5.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Of course I know down voting cost -2. But It's not that case. Also I haven't ever reached daily rep cap. So no need to consider that.

Comment: @Harikrishnan: +10 plus 4 x -2 makes +2 total rep change. My point being that you need to look at this as a *total* reputation change, not an individual vote.

Comment: OK.But I believe serial down voting for Questions/Answers of same user is not allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rep change reported for removed users is the total effect.  You don't know how many actions are involved in that.  So if you've been reasonably active yourself -- have lots of posts that could be voted on, have accepted answers, have edited, etc -- then just about any number is possible.  No breakdown is available.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe he downvoted 4 your posts and upvoted one of your answers. Then in total he gave you 2 reps. When he is removed, these two reps are removed. Only one event shown, summed up of all votes the removed user casted on your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you suggested an edit on a post and received 2 reps. The user (and his/her question) was removed, thus the 2 points you gained were taken back.

Comment: In that case the *post* is removed. I'd say this is the total from voting (so downvotes and upvotes)

Comment: @MartijnPieters if a post is removed (or deleted) then +2 gained by suggested edit would be taken back, correct?

Comment: Yes, but it should show up as a post deleted line, not a user removed line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, not if the post was deleted automatically when the user was deleted, which can happen for negatively-voted posts. This is the most likely explanation since it's the simplest and [has happened before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149845/user-was-removed-i-lost-2-rep#comment431511_149846).

Comment: @TimStone: ah, *evidence*! I'll accept Nick confirming it.

Comment: This is *very nearly* right, but it was the user who accepted the edit who was removed, not the user whose post was edited.

Comment: @Shog9 I get the logic of revoking +2 when the edited post is deleted, but doing it when a *reviewer* is removed is an odd thing to do. After all, there are multiple reviewers for each edit.