# What happens to edits approved by a user when the user is removed?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, deleted-accounts

I've just had a -2 rep adjustment because a "user was removed" which, I assume, comes from one of my suggested edits being approved by them.

Now the user's account is no more does my edit stand as is, or does it revert back to its pre-approval state in the review queue?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311251

Comment: These posts are related - by they concentrate mainly on the reputation aspect: [Don't revert reputation from suggested edits when reviewer's account is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296055) and [Lost reputation from suggested edit approval on post left behind when account is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249804). The same is briefly mentioned in the FAQ posts "[How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)" and "[What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470)".

Comment: In both cases, there is a link to this post on Meta Stack Overflow: [For "User was removed" event, why are editing reputation points rolled back? It can be sort of unfair?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311251) (The same one that is linked in the first comment and in the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [this comment by animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311251/for-user-was-removed-event-why-are-editing-reputation-points-rolled-back-it/311413#comment276621_311251)

> You actually lose reputation for suggested edits where the user removed was the final approver of the edit, because their user ID gets recorded on the "vote" which gives you the reputation. It doesn't revert all reputation you've gained from suggested edits on the users' posts.

The [next comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311251/for-user-was-removed-event-why-are-editing-reputation-points-rolled-back-it#comment276623_311251) confirms

> ...The edit and the post still exist. It's only the vote that's being deleted...

Comment: Ah! There's a MetaSO as well as a MetaSE and both cover the same topics. Go figure. Every day's a learning day!

Comment: They don't cover the same topics but there is overlap. Check their help centres