# Increment in Reputation on Stack Overflow related to removal of User

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

There is an increment of reputation `(total count 2)` in my Stack Overflow Profile and when I checked my Profile it showed `User was removed` as

[image]

Can anyone elaborate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user downvoted one of your post. And now the profile of that user is deleted. So you get that reputation back. But note that we can also lose reputation for this reason in opposite situation. e.g. A user upvoted your post and his/her profile is deleted (for any reason), you will lose reputation gained from him/her.

From [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/187824):

> A user who voted for one of your posts had their account deleted
>   (either by choice or due to violating the network's Terms of Service).
>   As a result, all of their votes were undone, and the rep you gained
>   from them (or lost because of them) was revoked.

Comment: but i can't see on which question /answer did this happened?can i see it?

Comment: No. We can not see that.

Comment: Thanks for referencing FAQ, at instance i was trying to find it in FAQs