# Is SO a zero sum game?

Tags: discussion

Well, not exactly zero-sum in the game sense, but I notice that my reputation goes down when a user closes his account.

I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it) question, which implies (but doesn't quite state outright) that points are *always* removed when user accounts are closed.  But it seems to me that this means that eventually everyone's reputation will go to zero (if they don't cancel their accounts first), since eventually all users will die, if nothing else.

Is this the way it works?  Is this the way it's intended to work?

Comment: Old accounts don't get deleted due to inactivity.

Comment: "eventually all users will die"....barring some form of apocalypse, we also will always get new users as well.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: [Has this been changed?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/)

Comment: @hammar `2. the user has not done anything of significance, ever`

Comment: @hammar: no, accounts are still purged, but 1-rep users can't vote at all, and generally 50-rep users with no posts haven't voted much either.

Comment: Somebody needs to get to work on a [morbid userscript](http://so.mrozekma.com/reputation-morbid.png)

Answer (score 18):

No. There's no reason to assume that everyone will eventually delete their accounts, and the removal of votes along with those members who do opt to delete their profiles is largely an implementation detail anyway - on those rare occasions when someone with a *lot* of participation requests it, we generally find ways to mitigate the disruption (assigning the votes to a dummy user, etc).

Anyway, calling it a zero-sum game would imply that in order for you to gain status, someone else needs to lose it - which is very much not the case.