# User was removed, got reputation +2

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

I've just noticed that on StackOverflow, my reputation increased by `+2`. I've checked it and I saw this:

[image]

I am not able to find out why I get that `+2` reputation if someone has been removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user in question most likely had downvoted one your posts.

When it was downvoted, you lost 2 points, which you now received back.

Another option is that you downvoted 2 answers by that user. With the user removal, answers that were downvoted also get deleted. The two points you lost for the downvotes are then reinstated.

Comment: No one has ever answered my question about this in chat, but as far as I'm concerned, if the reputation change is due to a post removal, it should show you what post whether the user was deleted or not. I should get around to asking a real Meta question about that...

Comment: @animuson: I am not certain either; but if there are *multiple* posts involved, it makes sense to show just one line (`user removed`).

Comment: The +2 could also be the net effect of several actions.  They could have upvoted one answer and downvoted 4, for example, or upvoted a question of yours and you downvoted 3 of their answers.  There are technically an infinite number of possible actions resulting in a net change of +2.

Comment: @Servy: Sure, that's why I used *most likely* and *another option*. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yep, just adding a few more less likely possibilities since it seemed other readers were having trouble extrapolating from your (perfectly accurate) answer.