# Is there a way to gain back points if "user was removed"?

Tags: support, reputation, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

I just lost points for no reason - some user gave me (probably) 15 downvotes, aka **-30** points. "Same s**t, different day", described in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it?lq=1) question.

I know how I lost my points, it is very well described in the question linked [above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it?lq=1). I want to know, whether or not there is any way how to get my points back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, those points are gone.

When a user is removed, all their actions (including votes) are deleted too. The points you lost were not downvotes, they were points *given* to you earlier by votes by that user. Perhaps that user had upvoted 3 of your answers (3 * 10 points makes 30).

If that user had *downvoted* your posts (15 downvotes in total), you would now have *regained* those points instead when the user is deleted.

(Note that that many downvotes usually are already undone when the anti-serial-voting script is run).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand why this question got closed? I didn't ask what happened, mentioned in question I **PERSONALLY** linked to it. I asked if it can be reverted. That I didn't find in the question linked.

Comment: @Michal I disagree that he didn't answer your question.  When a user is removed, all of their voting actions (specifically upvotes & downvotes) are removed with that user.  There is no way to replace those points, it is more like they never exisited

Comment: @Michal: First sentence of my answer: "No, those points are gone.". The point loss can *not* be reverted.

Comment: No no no, you answered my question perfectly, I already said thank you for that. I am saying, that I feel that this question is not an exact duplicate of that other question I posted hyperlink to, because it didn't tell me whether or not I can get my points back.

Comment: @Michal: We can update the FAQ, but I think it is clear enough. This is still a duplicate of that question as it covers the same ground, in the end.

Comment: Understood. I know now so it doesn't matter anymore. Anyway, I tried to delete the question as it is a duplciate, but it told me I can't because you answered it?

Comment: @Michal: Don't delete the question; it'll provide an alternative way to find the original question. It serves a purpose in and of itself.

Comment: I would like to stop the constant decrease of my points.

Comment: Points on Meta are mostly useless anyway.

Comment: I really disagree with those negative points I keep receiving. If you have the authority to delete this question, please do so, or please remove your answer, so I can delete it. I learnt my lesson. Thank you.

Comment: @Michal: I can only *vote* to have it deleted, it'd require another 2 such votes. I personally don't see any reason to vote for deletion. Again, reputation on Meta is next to useless anyway, don't take it so hard, it's not a punishment.

Comment: When I hit "delete" I get: "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead." If you remove your answer I will be able to delete it myself.

I am not asking you to consider reasons for deleting. I am asking you for benevolence to let me undo my mistake. I learnt what I should, why should I keep receiving negative votes then? Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @Michal: Your question and my answer are not solely for your benefit; *other* people should be able to find this and learn from it too. Deletion would bereft them of that opportunity. By posting on SE sites you agree to that premise.

Comment: OK, let them learn, but **WHY** should I gain negative votes for that?

Comment: @Michal: Why the obsession with reputation? What does it matter to you if you gain or loose a few votes here and there. There have been 7 downvotes and one upvote on your question, so you lost a paltry 9 points over this. *One* answer upvote would off-set that 'loss'. Find questions here on Meta to answer if this matters so much to you.