# Several issues with the "serial thing"

Tags: discussion, support, voting, serial-voting

[As you can see in the image, I was raged by someone yesterday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOzJn.png)

Then, I posted in Physics meta. I got several replies to the downvote. But, I can't understand the upvotes and today- the reversal. So, I came here and found this related one: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829)

Two things are bugging me now: (From the image)

1. **User was removed:** Which user was removed and what is it for that to do with me? - I'm just a 4-month old user. That's all. Then?
2. **Other upvotes:** Just a minute after the reversal, I got some of my old posts upvoted. Was that caused by the reversal? I have a thought that "No one could upvote the oldest posts *simultaneously* after the reversal". So, could reversal do such things?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I am not a downvoter but FYI: [Voting is different in Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which user was removed and what is it for that to do with me?

Users request for removal of their accounts for various reasons. The user who was removed has up/downvoted your questions, causing you to lose/gain rep respectively.

> So, could reversal do such things?

Removing users also removes their votes, so if I've downvoted you, the votes are repealed and you gain back the rep. Goes the other way too.

The serial upvoting reversal isn't linked to the user removal. It is conceivable that the vote fraud check scripts run after the removal scripts, to normalize reputation.

The "colouring" you mention looks more like CSS applying different styles for visited/not-visited links

Comment: Hi @Sathya. Thanks for your response. It was helpful *indeed* :-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy you're welcome.

Answer (score 6):

1. **User was removed:**
   Possible duplicate of [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/187824)
2. **Other upvotes:**
   **I assume** some one is following you. And after seeing *Serial upvoting reversed* he/she may upvoted your posts again *tactically* (with some gap in time).

   > I have a thought that "No one could upvote the oldest posts simultaneously after the reversal"

   Anyone can vote the same post again after his/her serial upvotes/downvotes are reversed. ([just confirmed it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#comment463974_126857))
3. **A side note:**
   Some posts are colored dark means you have visited those links<sup>*</sup>. And colored light means you haven't visited those links<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>* after you have cleared the history of the browser</sup>

Comment: I understood the sidenote. Man, I didn't think of that.. Thanks to you too :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Which user was removed and what is it for that to do with me?

That information is not available. It is a user who down-voted you, in your case. Once a user account is removed, the votes done with that user account are removed too, and that fact is reported in your reputation history to let you know why your reputation changed.

> Was that caused by the reversal?

No, It was not. The reversal removes the votes, and it shows the reputation lose/gain with an entry saying, "Serial upvpting/downvoting reversed." Somebody else voted your questions.

> I have a thought that "No one could upvote the oldest posts simultaneously after the reversal".

Everybody can vote your old posts, independently from the fact the script is reversing the serial votes, or not. Once the reversing is done, also who serial voted you can vote you on the same posts s/he serial voted.