# Does flagging a question plays role in the reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, flags

When we flag a question or answer, does it affect the reputation of the persons involved in that particular post?

Comment: whose reputation ? your's or the user whose post you flagged ?

Comment: @Raynold The individuals involved in that particular post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any post is deleted due to flags then reputation affects as per [deletion rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/187824) or if the user is removed (by moderators due to flags) then reputation affects as per [user was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/187824) rule.

But if any post receives [six *spam* or *offensive flags*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/187824) the author of the post loses 100 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal case flagging doesn't affect your own reputation. But say for example if you flag a user's post and the the user's account got deleted by moderator. Now if that user has voted on your post ever then those votes will get reversed. In this kind of case your own reputation may change.

Now flagging may affect to the user's reputation ( whose post you have flagged ) if his/her post( which has upvotes or downvotes) get deleted by moderator or users with above 15K reputation.