# My reputation is suddenly decreased by 10

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

My reputation is suddenly decreased by 10. There are neither downvotes nor the *user is deleted* in my reputation tab on Stack Overflow.

I already read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it) post.

Comment: Looks like your answer/question is deleted. Go to [your reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2169012/sam?tab=reputation) -> Click on *Show Removed Posts*. It will show you  your post which is deleted.

Comment: @hims056 thanks . i checked already but there is no removed post.

Comment: Maybe someone upvoted one of your answers, then reverted his/her vote during the grace period.

Comment: you [deleted an answer you got 1 upvote and 1 downvote for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17167201/208809). Is it that?

Answer (score 3):

In my knowledge there are two possibilities for this (I'm experienced both)

- **Post is Removed**
     When you answer to a question and you get a vote, if the question is removed. You'll lose your point
- **User was removed**
     When your question or answer is upvoted by a user, later that user profile was removed all the votes (upvotes or downvotes) from that user will be reset.

You can check your reputation changes and it's reason under the **Reputation** Tab in the Profile page.

[image: Reputation Tab]

Answer (score 2):

**Got it:**  when a user answers a question  on SO, if he got an upvote then later the post was removed by its owner, then the user's reputation decreases.

You can also check: go to  *reputation tab --> check the show remove post check box*

If you want your reputation back then go to that post and just undelete it.

Thanks hims056 and Gordon for your precious time.