# Removed post changes reputation

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

Why my rep. was modified on removed post even though I didn't earn anything on that particular post?

[image]

I tried to find the answer here but all I found was [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

Comment: You [suggested an edit to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3756727) so the +2 you got for that edit when it was approved were removed then the question was deleted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Indeed... everything is clear now :)

Comment: @hichris123 indeed... search engine did not work fine when adding new question. Vote for duplicate!

Answer (score 2):

The main reason that you get +2 on a post is because you edited it. That is true here. You can see the edit you suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3756727)