# User deletion rollback

Tags: support, deleted-accounts, rollbacks

SO,

I've faced reputation change with reason `"User was removed"` and found good explanation for this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it).

However, I want to know answers for following questions:

- When revoking all user votes it will affect not only reputation, but also *count* of upvotes/downvotes on question. Some badges are related to count of votes. Will the corresponding badge be also revoked/granted? Example: Question has 99 score and it is 100 upvotes after 1 downvote (i.e. downvote was first). After removing user which gave that 1 downvote - will that question be [famous](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question)? Or else - question has 100 upvotes. After removing any of users which gave their vote to quesion - will the corresponding badge be lost?
- Will chat history with such user be removed as well? Or it will be saved to transcript or something?
- What will happen to edit history on posts, which removed user did (i.e. with revisions that removed user did)? Will I be able to see full revision history in such cases - or revisions, made by those user, will be removed too? If yes, then what if last revision on some post was from that user? Will it be rolled back?
- What will happen to such user's closing votes? Will they be revoked too? If yes, then what will happen with questions that were closed with one vote of that user? (Reopened?). Same for deletion votes. Will deleted questions with vote from that user restored?
- How to find, deletion of which user caused reputation change? (That "User was removed" doesn't point to any meaningful information)

Comment: Re. badges, those won't get revoked. As a rule, once you have a badge you keep it even if you no-longer fit the criteria.

Comment: I've noticed the chat transcripts still include deleted users, including their icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Badges are not revoked once the conditions to granting them no longer apply. However, when you receive the next badge of the same type, you won't get it (because you already have one extra).
- Much like comments and answers (which are not deleted), I'm pretty sure the messages will be dissociated from his account, rather than deleted.
- Edits will not be rollbacked/altered, they will be dissociated.
- Close votes from the user will expire, existing questions already closed by the deleted user will not be reopened.
- You cannot, as that would mean you'd know who voted for you :)

Comment: Only one thing - what exactly means "dissociated" ?

Comment: @AlmaDo: It means that the name of the contributor returns to `userNNNN` and stops linking, basically, the post remains, but it's impossible to tell who made it.

Comment: Just a minor nitpicky comment - Badge tags do get revoked if you no longer meet the criteria.

Comment: @psubsee2003 thank you, that's important