# Regarding reputation change

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, stackexchange-2.0

I usually found that when I am not doing anything on Stackoverflow my reputation shows me some -ve change. Whenever I looked to the reputation change history it showed mu user deleted. 
Now this time my reputation changed with -94 point with no logs and details. How I can get to know the reason behind that.

**Edit:**
Recent history change show me nothing but the last update of +15 that I received on Jan 21. But I an unable to track my -94 reputation that SO show me today. there is no track of this in history

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recent Reputation History Changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)

Comment: I'm not sure of those dupes apply here because the OP explains that he is aware of the user removed case.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot where you see that -94?

Comment: Any deleted questions? Check your recently deleted posts.

Comment: Yep, [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NLvVrAmzToUJ:stackoverflow.com/users/2392564/ashish-aggarwal+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) holds a copy of your profile from February 19 where you had 2215 points. Weird.

Comment: I can only think of one thing: we have been hacked and all our FIP are worthless now

Comment: Possibly it is a post with 10 upvotes and 2 downvotes that got removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clicking "show removed posts" in the bottom of your rep tab:

[image]

Anything new you can see?

Comment: Perfect Answer. now I got my answer