# How do serial upvoters not get caught?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

So given that there is an entire tag on it, that would suggest that people are getting away with serial upvoting. How do they do it?

Comment: They have a lot of Trix up their sleeves.

Comment: If they're getting away with the serial upvoting, it hasn't been noticed that they're serial upvoting. To do that, they would likely have to _not_ actually be serial upvoting, which would make it _look_ like they're not serial upvoting. That said, if they're getting away with it and therefore we're not noticing it... How are we supposed to know how it's being done, since we wouldn't know/notice it's being done?

Comment: If you *look* at the tag, most of the questions are about side effects where the serial voting reversal did something unexpected, or where votes should not have been reversed. Some are about ideas to make detection easier. Finally, some are manual reports of apparent, small-scale serial voting that was not caught. (Usually serial downvoting; most people don't report serial upvotes that aren't reversed. I can't imagine why not.) So your actual question is about a small fraction of a modest fraction of a moderately-sized tag... not "an entire tag".

Comment: @DanBron Does that mean that they are also *Powerful and Great*?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist More like that have absolutely no sympathy for starving rabbits.

Answer (score 8):

Simple answer - They don't get away with it.

Votes are always getting annulled and [users being removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it). If users repeatedly vote for the same user/users then they will get detected and they will get dealt with.

If they're just voting on lots of posts and lots of different users, then it won't be dealt with. But then if that's the case is there a problem there that needs dealing with?

Comment: The answer is too simplistic. There exists a size of voting ring N/complexity of voting graph C which are beyond the capabilities of automatic detection scripts. However, N and C are kept secret, which in itself is a good deterrent. The _ultima ratio regis_ is a manual investigation, though.