# Why were reputation points subtracted?

Tags: support, reputation

I have suddenly lost 30 points from my reputation, without any indication of why. According to Help center, I lose points if

- your question is voted down: −2
- your answer is voted down: −2
- you vote down an answer: −1
- you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
- one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100

None of these apply. Why would I suddenly lose 30 points?

Comment: 30 reputation. On what site? You are a member of a number. Did you go to your profile reputation page? Did you check the "show removed posts" on it?

Comment: On the ELU site. I see now what happened--a question that i got upvotes for has been migrated to Meta. On that page, I still have those 30 points.

Comment: Actually, I don't have those points. I see below where you say it's as if no points were awarded, which is fine, but as points were awarded and then removed, it seems to me this should be included among the way you can lose points on the Reputation Help Page. Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11):

I will assume that you are talking about your English Language & Usage profile (as it seems to fit the bill).

Going to your the [reputation tab of your profile there](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/66965/surlawda?tab=reputation&sort=time) (and checking the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom) will show (with the time sort) that  question you had answered was migrated to a the child-meta.

The question and the answers on it were removed from English Language & Usage and the reputation associated with them is gone, as if it was never awarded.

Since the question is *about* ELU, it does indeed belong on the child-meta, which is likely why it got migrated.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thanks. Maybe that should be indicated on the page that explains how reputation points are won and lost? I like this site, but I must admit, even after more than a year here, I am quite confused about how it all works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

The help centre is not 100% complete. This system is super complicated and telling people all the possibilities can just be confusing. Reasons for losing rep not listed there include:

- the user who voted your post up deleted their account. See [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it?s=1|12.1879)
- the post was removed - your question was deleted (by you or others) or migrated or your answer was deleted (by you or others) or was on a question that was deleted or migrated

These can also cause a **gain** in rep if the action being undone by the removal involved downvotes.

There are edge cases here about not always losing rep for user-was-removed, and about migrations to a nonmeta site where you have an account, and if the help centre lists all of that in great detail people are just going to run screaming away.

Comment: I get it. Thanks. Actually, the whole points thing is something I really don't like--but knowing the whys and wherefores is always helpful. Thank you.