# Make it easier to disassociate from (fine) community wiki posts

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, post-disassociation

**tl;dr** If the community wiki posts has proven its worth, provide an easy way (button) to original authors to disassociate from it.

---

The [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/489715) tells us

> The original author still receives notifications for substantial edits or comments on the post.

This can be annoying and lead to unwanted consequences, e. g. like that edit war over an accepted FAQ [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/489715). It's even more so when you never earned reputation through it, e. g. when you converted an answer in someone else's comment(s) to an actual CW answer. But also all answers to CW questions.

I understand and agree with the need to prevent abuse, like posting inappropriate answers as CW to avoid a reputation hit. That's why I suggest the following to ensure that the CW post was okay (bonus points if you find out where I got these numbers from). The "disassociate" button should only appear when

1. The CW post has been **visible** for at least **60 days**.
2. The CW post has at least a **score** of **3**.

We may not need to be so strict about bullet point 2, perhaps simply a positive score could suffice. It'd make it hard to abuse that system. The visibility part to avoid immediate deletion and undeletion, for sure.

I know, it would be some work for the developers, but I believe it would be a slight improvement for users and CW in general (makes the option of contributing useful CW content more appealing).

**What do you think about the idea and its implementation?**

Comment: Good idea. However moderators should be able to **always** disassociate a post. (maybe also when not CW). Also a revision entry should be added like "Post Disassociated". (This feature would not be used as a way to fully disassociate content per the CC-BY-SA license, only to remove the ownership field. No revisions would be affected)

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard Giving moderators that ability would be a different feature request. SE sheds some light onto why post disassociation is such a pain in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300658/489715). Since I understand this, my request concerns users themselves, but only for a specific type of post (CW) that meets specific criteria to avoid abuse like getting around a post ban or so. Much fewer people would be affected by this. And it seems to laborious for an everyday abuse attempt.

Comment: yes, I saw that your post is about saying "I don't want to receive notifications for this post" but I still think moderators should be able to do this and should be exempted from time/vote based limits. This could be for example for a [tag:faq] that would cause a lot of notifications *in the beginning*. Also all actions (like this) need to be tracked to be able to recognize abuse.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard It seems that SE wants to keep the number of disassociations low and that's why they make it so complicated. I could imagine that they don't want mods to have the ability because then a) it'd be easier to request (pester mod about it) and more work for them, b) mods may not have the necessary tools to detect all possible kinds of abuse related to post disassociation.