# Fix attribution for deleted account

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

How can I get the attribution fixed on a deleted account? I deleted the account, then created a new one with the same name, but old answers have not been attributed to the new account.

Note that I was told that deleting an account is the only way to remove attribution, and that moderators could restore it later on other posts. Was this a lie, has it screwed me?

Comment: _" I deleted the account, then created a new one"_ Why did you do so in 1st place??

Comment: Related: [Is a refusal to disassociate deleted posts in compliance with the CC BY-SA license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300594/is-a-refusal-to-disassociate-deleted-posts-in-compliance-with-the-cc-by-sa-licen)

Comment: To remove attribution on a different post.

Comment: So, you [threw the baby with the bathwater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_throw_the_baby_out_with_the_bathwater)? Did you not know this would be the effect?

Comment: That is the only mechanism stack overflow has to remove attribution, or so I was told.

Comment: @ゼーロ And this is the consequence of that, as you were well aware at the time that you did it.

Comment: I'd suggest this is status by design...

Answer (score 13):

> but old answers have not been attributed to the new account

Nor will they be.  They were answers posted to the old account, which doesn't exist anymore, because you decided that you didn't want the account, or attribution for any of its contributions.

Comment: Staff have restored attribution for other deleted accounts. Your answer is obviously wrong since I clearly did not indicate that I didn't want the account.

Comment: @ゼーロ so you don't consider *deleting it* a pretty clear indication?

Comment: No, as I explained to staff the goal and they said deletion was the only option. I noted that other deleted accounts had been restored. Have I been trolled?

Comment: You were told deletion would sort the issue. You have not been trolled. It has sorted the issue.

Comment: It's completely buggered the issue. It's far worse than it started out.

Comment: @ゼーロ obviously most of us aren't privy to the full story, but I doubt you were trolled. If you wanted a single post disassociated, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/248731 would have told you to use the contact links. The consequence of account deletion, the irreversible disassociation of all content, is clear from e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account.

Comment: I used the link, the staff said I could request attribution in a private email. I really think they lied about that and made me destroy a considerable amount of work.

Comment: I followed the story with interest - although I didn't see what was in your note to the CMs, I did see what recommendations were made to you on various posts.You were told about dissociation, and you were told about deletion being permanent.

Comment: Please delete this answer. If the staff respond to my request I will post the content of their email.

Comment: @ゼーロ You should not ask users to delete their answer. They invested their time, please respect that.

Comment: I want to delete the question. I tried to seconds after the answer appeared. They beat me to it by a hair.

Comment: If you're asking questions without intending for them to stick around, you will very quickly be rate limited, even on M.SE. Deletion isn't meant to be used as a way to shed downvotes, either.

Comment: @fbueckert It'll take quite some time on Meta, it's a *lot* different than other sites.  It's so tuned down that most users providing lots of bad content on meta end up needing to get manually suspended by a moderator before the post ban kicks in.

Comment: I knew it was much more lax, but I didn't think it was so lax as to allow rage quitters enough leeway to never kick in. Sure, we don't want to be an echo chamber, but how much rope do you give someone before you decide their contributions just aren't worth the time? Seems to just add more work for staff.

Comment: @fbueckert Meta gets so much less traffic than most sites, and has so many moderators actively following it, reading just about *every* question that comes in, that manual intervention is far more reasonable than on other sites.  Additionally, due to the nature of the site, lots of people can end up with lots of heavily downvoted posts without necessarily being bad actors (by simply proposing changes others don't think would be a good idea), and blocking such users is a problem.

Comment: @Servy I can understand the more lax requirements. I just think that at some point, someone's bad faith actions should have consequences. Now that I think about it, though, that's a really hard thing to program. I guess manual intervention is the only way.