# Deleting my account is not working

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I have been trying to delete my account for a few days but nothing is happening. I went to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/delete/9206 and clicked the button where it said it would take 24 hours.   However <strike>72</strike>48 hours have passed at least and still nothing.

There was a notice saying that it was due to be deleted in 60 minutes which counted down but at the end nothing happened.

Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: I'll investigate and see if a cog fell out; I can confirm that the system [definitely knows about it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xpex.png) - digging...

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you.

Comment: By my records, it hasn't been 72 hours - it was logged at "2018-04-18 14:12:48Z", but yes, I agree that it is overdue; I'm still investigating.  Just for context: there isn't a large backlog, so it isn't a catastrophic system fail or anything.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks so much. I have clicked delete a number of times now on different SE sites as it wasn't working but maybe the first time was "2018-04-18 14:12:48Z".

Comment: FWIW - your question has made us realise that some parts of this flow were unnecessarily awkward, and cause the useful text explaining what is going on to disappear (meaning: we display useful text for the first 24 hours, but when it goes past that, the text disappears); we're looking into improving that aspect

Comment: @SonicWizard it's not really a duplicate. See the comments and answer.

Comment: @Lembik Here on Meta Stack Exchange, we close questions as duplicates of [tag:faq] questions if the answer is already covered in a subsection of the [tag:faq] question (even though the questions themselves aren't duplicates). In this case, the answer is already covered in the second and third bullets of the proposed target.

Comment: @SonicWizard OK but what about the identified bug?

Comment: @Lembik The bug is that there is no deletion notice on your profile during the developer hold-up period. This is already mentioned in the FAQ as a known issue.

Comment: @SonicWizard this has now been resolved

Comment: @MarcGravell So a deletion notice is now shown on accounts that are held up for a developer to check? Can you please update the FAQ?

Comment: "This account is scheduled to be deleted 8 mins ago." Well, better than _no_ message at all... 

Answer (score 2):

As [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300185/208518) explains, your high-rep profiles need human intervention before deletion, which only occurs after the 24h have gone by. All in all: everything's working as expected, and someone just needs to have a look at your profile — which will hopefully happen later today. No need to ask for deletion again <strike>(as the system will have informed you once you retried it</strike> :)

It looks like there was a bug somewhere, since we should have been telling you earlier that this would happen, but *probably* weren't. Workin' on fixing that to avoid future confusion ;)

Comment: Thank you.  I won't complain again for another 24 hours :)

Comment: "Workin' on fixing that"... was it fixed by now?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309260/deleting-my-account-is-not-working/309261?noredirect=1#comment1008291_309260