# No way to change or delete Stack Exchange login

Tags: support, stack-exchange, user-accounts, openid, linked-accounts

My Stack Exchange login is registered to a email address on domain that will soon be owned by another person. For security reasons, I would like to deactivate my login on Stack Exchange and dissociate it with my identity in future.

I've tried removing this login from my StackOverflow, but after I logged in back to it I am logged in on StackOverflow again. Anyway, detaching is not the same as deactivating login.

As I have many other Stack Exchange sites without other log-in options than this OpenID, it may be better to change the email of the OpenID. But I did not find option for this.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [contact us](/contact) to have the login itself deleted, but I'd like to clarify that this will **not** itself solve the issue you're facing.

The problem is that we still hold an obsolete Email field on the user profile for every site that we're diligently working to remove in every place so that it can be completely dropped from the database at some point.

Because that email is still set for your profiles, *even if you delete the login itself*, if someone else really had access to the old account and recreated the login they'd still get auto-merged into your account as a matching credential. The login existing isn't the problem but rather the email still being attached to your account in some way is. If there is a strong concern that a past employer might use your email for nefarious purposes like that, make sure you point that out so we can null the email off your profiles too.

That said, and more importantly, **you do not have another credential set up for your account**. You need to do that before we delete anything. All you've done so far is changing your email in the Email Settings section, which correctly updates where notifications for your account will be sent, but does *not* allow you to login with that email address.

That email should appear under the "Other" section in My Logins. It needs to appear under the "Stack Exchange" section in order to be usable as a login credential. Simply use the "add more logins" button on that page, type in the same email and a password, and complete the process to register that email so that it will be properly attached to your account. Note that it is not possible to simply change the email address connected to the actual credential - you must create a new one and delete the old one.

I know that's a lot of information to process, but if you screw something up along the way we have a variety of things we can do to help you back into your account. Hopefully we'll be able to simplify this process a lot soon enough once that treacherous Email field is finally gone. As someone who works in support and has seen all the annoyances of this system, we can all probably expect a complete revamp of how this stuff works similar - only a matter of time before it reaches [deletion process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300185/weve-drastically-simplified-the-user-deletion-process) levels of annoyance.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed response. I appreciate that.