# Retaining negative meta posts from deleted accounts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, down-votes, meta, deleted-accounts

The way I understand it, when a user's account is deleted, so are all his posts that have a negative score (see #8 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222)). This makes a lot of sense to me on a main site. But as we know on meta voting means something different than on main, and a negatively voted post can still be worth keeping around as an important part of the discussion. (I'm sure some of the longtime users can point to a number of good examples where a negatively voted meta post was accepted, implemented, or at least heavily discussed.)

My feature request is that negatively voted posts of deleted users *not* get deleted **on meta only**.

Comment: When did you get this understanding from? [From what I understand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131666), either their posts get deleted (if they're a spammer) or their posts just get anonymized. Can you provide a link to information somewhere stating that negatively scored posts get automatically deleted with the user?

Comment: @animuson http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222 See #8

Comment: Interesting... I'd never heard of that before.

Comment: @animuson I've added the link to the question.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest a more general change to this mechanism. Currently, even if you have highly upvoted answers on a question with a negative score, all of those will be deleted along with the question if the owner of the question has his account deleted.

I suggest that a similar logic to the self-deletion of questions is applied here. This means, once there are upvoted answers on the question you can't self-deleted it, and this should extend to the automatic deletion upon account removal. I'd probably set the threshold a bit higher for saving the post on account removal, maybe something like "questions with a negative score that have at least one answer with +3 score are not deleted".

Requesting deletion of your account allows you to remove stuff that you are intentionally prohibited to remove by usual means. You can remove questions that have upvoted answers and you can remove all your votes, both which are not possible by conventional means. This is an inconsistent behaviour that should be changed, in my opinion.

Comment: Agreed.  Or raise flags for posts that would otherwise be deleted.  (And I especially agree that meta shouldn't be automatically culled.)