# Prevent Knowledge Loss?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, deleted-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What EXACTLY happens when I ask to delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131665/what-exactly-happens-when-i-ask-to-delete-my-account)

I have been using Stack Overflow for couple of years (actively contributing for last few weeks) and in my opinion this is the best Q&A website I ever used. But Stack Overflow value is in people, their interesting questions and amazing answers.

But what (I hope that will never happen) if one or a few top contributors, say, people with reputation over 100k, requested their accounts to be removed. Would SO loose thousands of valuable answers or is there any mechanism which would *change* owner of those answers to some "*non-real person*" account?

Did you have any case like that in the past?

**EDIT**

I agree that this question is a duplicate of [What EXACTLY happens when I ask to delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131665/205246) question.

Comment: "When you delete an account, the account is anonymized..., but **no posts are deleted**. They just appear to come from some anonymous user who doesn't have an account anymore..." ([quote source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131666/165773))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Would SO loose thousands of valuable answers or is there any mechanism which would change owner of those answers to some "non-real person" account?

No, even if the person is removed, their answers and questions are preserved.

It is possible they try to delete all answers/questions manually, but the system would detect it.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask to have your account disassociated from your posts.

This means the answers would be preserved.

Do note that deleted posts are not really removed from the database, and remain visible to moderators and users with 10k or more reputation. Mods can undelete, high-rep users can vote to undelete posts.