# Can I leave behind editable posts after account deletion?

Tags: discussion, edits, user-accounts, community-wiki, deleted-accounts

First of all I am aware of the earlier Q&A: [What EXACTLY happens when I ask to delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131665/what-exactly-happens-when-i-ask-to-delete-my-account)

However my question is this: *after I delete my account, can my posts and answers still be edited?*

I wish to delete my accounts on SE sites.  However, I'd like to leave the posts in a form that can be edited and commented on by the community, if they so choose.  If the posts turn read-only after account deletion, that would be a bummer.

Is this already the case, or do I have to turn every single (!) post/answer into Community Wiki?

It would also be interesting to know if it's possible to convert a post by a deleted user into community wiki when the edit threshold is crossed posthumously.

Comment: What makes you think that deleting an account makes the posts uneditable? Those are two different things, any post can be edited always, no matter who the author is.

Comment: @ShadowWizard because of a lack of experience in deleting my account(s).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I suppose technically that's "any non-locked post can be..."

Comment: In theory, people only do that once. That's what deletion is after all

Comment: @Jon true, but deleting account does not cause lock on any of the posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - they can. They will just not have a user associated with it. One of the old users on SU did that, and her posts can be edited to this day. Any reputation from them will probably get chucked in a bitbucket , but they will certainly be the same as a question asked by a user who's still active in that regard.

Also, [CW's complex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/135565) - the idea being it's meant to be "shared" ownership of a post rather than being owned by nobody. It's never intended to be a way to "not get reputation" for an answer or question and to a large extent [is meant to be rarely used](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/). It's certainly not /dev/null/ by intention.

Comment: Ah I see.  So the Community Wiki is like `/dev/null`, with a cooler name?

Comment: And not write-only, that is.