# User was removed ... Ok, why am I getting punished for it?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, deleted-accounts

Today my reputation was decreased because of 'User was removed' criteria.

First of all the information provided about this on the reputation page is quite inadequate.

It does not explain, who got removed?(Don't care about this) but I would like to know where my points got deducted on which question and would like some more detailed explanation for all the points awarded or deducted by SO, I always have to go hunting now what does this mean.

Can we have a better messaging system for reputation? The main reason I am writing this question is that found out from what "User was removed" means.

> A user who voted for one of your posts had their account deleted
>   (either by choice or due to violating the network's Terms of Service).
>   As a result, all of their votes were undone, and the rep you gained
>   from them (or lost because of them) was revoked.

Some user broke the rules and got himself thrown out.

- A user I am not associated with.
- A user I don't even know who he is.
- A user I have got nothing to do with.

Why am I getting punished for his acts?

Comment: "Punished"? Let's put it this way: If the user was cheating, why should you keep the *bonus* you got from them? Very often, such users are deleted due to cheating on voting, for instance. It's just more fair all around to wipe out any reputation gained from such a user.

Comment: From what I see from your profile, you only lose 10 rep, and that worth only 1 upvote on answer.

Comment: Related: [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740/176533).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Deal with it and move on.**

The only way for reputation to be a (somewhat) useful metric is if it accurately reflects what your peers think of your contributions. A removed account is no longer your peer (in the context of Stack Overflow, obviously). Assuming the account was removed due to violating the network's Terms of Service, one might argue that you are being rewarded by not having your reputation tainted by upvotes from an account that... wasn't really worth keeping around.

Concentrate on asking useful questions and providing awesome answers. Soon enough you'll realize that a few lost points are not worth losing sleep over.