# Badges for upvoted answers, but not accepted

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

We have `Tenacious` and `Unsung Hero` badges for zero score accepted answers. Can we have something similar for answers with up-votes, but not accepted, especially when there are no other up-voted answers for the question.

I like to wear my badges.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I've got four up-votes, but no convincing answer. What have mods got to say about this proposal.

Comment: Does it really matter? And you will get Nice Answer badge when you get 10 votes.

Comment: `I've got four up-votes, but no convincing answer.  What have mods got to say about this proposal` - [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) has **509** up-votes and no official response added ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of badge is important, even more so than Unsung Hero and Tenacious.

I just did a totally unscientific survey and looked at a page of 50 unanswered questions that were a couple of weeks old.

Of the 50 questions on the page, 27 had no answers at all - but the remaining 23 had one to three answers.

I would suggest that answers counting towards this (series of) badge(s) would be something like:

`The highest scoring answer on a question that has no accepted answers 30 days later`

Rather than 30 days, it could be the same interval as the clean-up routine, so that answers are counting towards this badge the first time the question and answer survive an automated clean-up.

A lot of the answers in my survey had no votes at all - but I don't know if that is general, and I think that makes an upvoted answer in this category even more interesting.

Also, a lot of the questions (both with and without answers) were asked by users with less than 100 rep - this badge might make it more attractive to answer even if you suspect that this is a hit'n'run where the OP will never be heard from again.

Answer (score 0):

The [Populist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/62/populist) badge appears to serve a purpose similar to your request:

> Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x

It differs slightly from your request in that it requires a question with an additional accepted answer, but is very close.

Comment: `Populist` is applicable for a single answer.