# What happens to a question when a user is deleted?

Tags: support, questions, answers, down-votes, up-votes

Say a user asked a question. He had answers on it, as well as upvotes and downvotes, but then his account is deleted for some reason. What will happen to all the questions, answers, upvotes and downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user is *deleted*, all questions/answers *except* downvoted ones are kept.

When a user is *destroyed*, the account and all posts are deleted. This is usually for spammers.

The votes get removed in both cases, and affected users will see a `-xyz User was removed` entry in their reputation history.

See also: [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted)

Comment: I assume those questions/answers are then attributed to the community user?

Answer (score 3):

- Questions without upvotes or upvoted (or accepted) answers are deleted normally.
- Upvoted questions or questions with upvoted answers are *anonymized* (meaning their author becomes `userNNNNNNNN`.
- Answers with 0 or negative score are deleted.
- Answers with a positive score are anonymized.