# Why do answerers get a penalty for user removal?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

Today I was notified about a novel event regarding my reputation.

[image]

It appears a user account was deleted, whose question was answered by me and also **up-voted**. So **10+15(accepted)=25** was deducted from my account!

Why did I receive a penalty for that? Doesn't this rule discourage a user from providing answers?

Comment: Related: [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the reason is that the user no longer exists, so does their up-vote really count anymore? I lean towards the current policy on this. Consider that some users are removed for nefarious reasons (e.g. voting irregularities) and the fact that a vote belongs to someone. So, when a user gets deleted, their questions become disassociated from them, their rep disappears, and all of their votes are revoked.

Now, if that person had down-voted you, I bet you wouldn't be complaining that you get +2 rep back.

Comment: From my point of view i would say,positive or negative that doesn't matter.But i think this is a very weird rule,an answerer must not get penalty for that!

Comment: @ridoy well, sorry, I understand your point of view, but that's the way it works.

Comment: well,from above reported duplicate link i found the rules,for users who have big reputation,in that case if they delete their account then it doesn't harm anyone,but who holds small reputation they harm others when they delete their account.So while giving answer,first i need to found that who have how many points and then think about future,and then answer.Very funny rules!

Comment: @ridoy That's a terrible way to determine whether or not to answer a question. Not all the votes on your answer will come from the user who asked the question, if any of them even do.

Comment: Keep in mind @ridoy that the rules have already been relaxed for significantly upvoted content (>= 3 score) that has been on the site for more than 60 days. But in principle the reputation you have reflects the community's trust in you. If part of that community is no longer there to back that up, it's not all that strange (in that light) to remove the reputation they gave you (or took away from you).

Comment: @ridoy - In this case, I think it makes sense, because the user that was removed was a fake account created by another user to work around system voting safeguards. They also appeared to be using this account to skirt question-asking limits, so it's probably best not to let them get away with this.

Comment: @Bart Can you provide any details on precisely how the rule has been relaxed? Preferably a meta answer where this is discussed?

Comment: @p.s.w.g See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work as well as http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/

Comment: @BradLarson, then while giving answer how could i determine whether the questioning user account is fake or not?

Comment: @ridoy you can't. Focus on providing good answers and not worrying about whether any of the up-votes you get will be permanent.