# Prevent moderators misplacing their diamonds in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

See [Why do answerers get a penalty for user removal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193599/why-answerers-get-penalty-for-user-remove) with the first answer having a comment by Animuson.

On my screen the username and the diamond are on different lines because of a page break. I think there should be a non-breaking space between the name and the diamond so it's on the same line.

Comment: You know, it's *really hard* to train these new moderators to hold on tight to their diamonds as they wander around different apps.

Comment: While we're at it the "asked X mins ago" should probably be on the same line.

Comment: Oops. I mean the "X mins ago" on comments. The one in questions seems fine.

Comment: “X mins ago” can be split across lines on the full site. Why shouldn't it be?

Comment: @AndrewBarber I thought the duct tape would work. :(

Comment: @gilles: I think it looks a bit weird when split but I guess it's not a big issue, or an issue for all. If it is split then there's always space on the line for it all to be moved down; I think it makes sense to do so. Tempted to say possibly everything from the dash should move down if it will get split and can fit. Maybe I'm looking at the android app with too critical an eye! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have eliminated the extra space between the mod and their precious diamond.  It will be in the next release:  v0.1.17