# Bounties and pending delete users

Tags: support, bounties, deleted-accounts

Sometimes users instead of "I quit and I'm taking my ball" do a "I quit and here are all my balls" by awarding bounties.  The steps behavior of the bounty system in this case doesn't appear to be well documented and leaves the possibility for poor user experiences for people answering the question.

1. Can a user be deleted with a pending bounty? (note: [Destroying a user can leave a bounty open on a deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115503/destroying-a-user-can-leave-a-bounty-open-on-a-deleted-question/116933#116933) suggests this can be the case, though its something that is 'exceedingly rare')
2. What happens to bounties that have been awarded after a user is deleted?  I know that users who are deleted have their votes retracted, but what about bounties?

Comment: Related (and shameless plug): [Is it appropriate for a user trying to delete an account to dump all their rep via bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220066/is-it-appropriate-for-a-user-trying-to-delete-an-account-to-dump-all-their-rep-v)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pending bounties are [transferred to the Community User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties&sort=offered) when an account is deleted.

The bounty will still be auto-awarded, if the criteria are met (answered after the bounty started, with at least 2 upvotes or the answer was accepted). If the to-be-deleted user marked an eligible answer as accepted the full bounty will be awarded, otherwise only half.

As such, there is no block on users being deleted when a bounty is still pending.

Comment: That makes sense when one looks at the [offered bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties&sort=offered) tab of Community.  Thank you.