# Why did I lose 5 reputation after a "user was removed"?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-accounts

On my Math.SE account, it says "user was removed" and 5 reputation was deducted. What does this mean?

Comment: Questions on the operation of any site should be referred to the site Meta. In this case you should ask on [meta.math.se](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: appreciated for the support!

Comment: A user who upvoted one of your questions got removed, thus the upvote and the reputation you received for it got removed as well.

Comment: This in no way is a slight to you (although I understand it is irritating for you), it is just an effect of what happens when annother user is deleted (for whatever reason). It is as if they never existed

Comment: @RichardTingle there are exceptions, e.g. if user who voted a lot is removed, the dev team manually transfer his votes to Community account so they're not lost... but in most cases there's no point to bother.

Answer (score 5):

A user who upvoted for one of your posts had their account deleted (this could happen due to several reasons, such as violating TOS,  abusive voting behavior etc.). As a result, all the votes they cast were undone, and the reputation you got from them (or lost because of them) was revoked. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) discusses this in more detail.