# Delete account without revoking votes

Tags: feature-request, deleted-accounts

How can I delete my account without revoking votes? I feel like my votes are a contribution to the site analogous to answers and I dont want to remove them.

I found a 2 year old duplicate with 738 upvotes and the answer in favor, does this mean its going to or is already implemented? Or are such discussions useless?  [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted?rq=1)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with leaving your account inactive?

Comment: You can't eat the cake and leave it whole. What you suggest exists, but as manual process of the dev team who need to transfer the votes to community account to preserve them. They'll do it only in extreme cases, e.g. user with thousands of votes where his leaving would make big impact. Otherwise it's really not worth their time.

Comment: You walk away and never login again.  Done.  It even takes far less time/effort than going through the process of having your account deleted.

Comment: To be absolutely sure you'll never login: (1) If you used real email to sign up (how quaint of you), change it to [10 minute mail](http://10minutemail.com/). (2) remove login methods other than SE itself; (3) change your SE password to a [random string](http://www.random.org/passwords/) without writing it down; (4) remove all cookies containing "stack". Problem solved; the account is not yours anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you can't. You could email the team and ask if they'll keep your votes, but they  probably won't; only accounts with enough votes to seriously impact much of the userbase get that treatment. Physics is smaller than SO, but I don't think your < 2k votes there are enough.

Comment: I have 2k on physics, 3k on math. Maybe they could tell us what is enough.

Comment: I meant physics, not sure where skeptics came from. And even math is 2400, and still most likely not enough; math gets lots of votes.

Comment: how much is the number anyways? where is it written? can somebody give a link?

Comment: @NKN No, it's on a case-by-case basis. So far, I only know of 2 instances, and both were old accounts, very high rep, and lots of votes.

Comment: I'm not sure it's even worth the time to email and ask. Is this something they've ever considered before? (I could be unaware of something here, so I'm asking earnestly...)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Twice, that I know of. Not sure how much is public, so see TL

Comment: Hmmm... interesting! Learn something new every other day!

Comment: @user224104 there isn't a hard-and-fast rule or a magic number.  In *very rare* cases the team will decide that the impact of losing the votes is significant enough to take action.  Do not count on it.