# Do votes get canceled if voting privilege is lost?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, privileges

If I'm below 15 reputation, I can't alter the public score of an answer/question.

Suppose I gain the privilege by getting the required rep and vote some posts up. Then, for any reason, I fall below 15 and lose the ability to vote. What about the votes I already did cast?

Do post scores get altered by ignoring my vote, or will they stay the same? In other words, is losing a privilege retroactive?

If yes, what about when I gain my privilege back? Are my votes automatically restored, or do I have to cast them again from scratch?

I made the easiest example, but this applies to any higher privilege

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your existing votes will continue to count towards the score of the question or answer. The only times when your votes are removed/cancelled (other than you doing it yourself) is when your account is deleted (unless, as ShadowWizard mentions, you've cast a lot of votes), and when so-called serial voting by you is reversed.

Comment: Actually when a user with many votes is deleted, the team might intervene and preserve their votes, as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/152859). (This answer is not really wrong, but also lacking this info.)