# Do my past votes stay if I drop below the rep threshold for voting?

Tags: support, voting, privileges

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, but I couldn't find a dupe.

Let's say I have 60 rep. I upvote an answer. Then I get downvoted 25 times, and drop to 10 rep. Does the upvote I gave before dropping stay?

Or I have 150 rep. I downvote an answer. Then I give away 100 rep in a bounty. Does the downvote I gave earlier stay?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278179/do-votes-get-canceled-if-voting-privilege-is-lost