# Does high rep or high vote count determine whether the votes are removed when the user is deleted?

Tags: discussion, voting, deleted-accounts

If a high rep user is deleted, his "votes aren't removed as that can be destructive to the site".

I'm wondering:

1. How high is "high rep"
2. What if a user was lower reputation than the cut-off line, but was a very active user (with tons of votes).

How would a situation like this be handled

Is it done on a per-account basis at the discretion of the moderators?

Comment: at the discretion of SE employees, not of the moderators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"High rep" doesn't mean a whole lot, because it's an arbitrary number that differs from person-to-person, and even has potentially different meaning in several places of our system. For the purposes of deletion, we always considered a user "high rep" if they had 1,000 reputation. In the old deletion system, that was enough to kick you out of the automated system and send a support ticket to us instead.

But reputation and votes are not the ultimate deciding factors in whether or not votes are preserved. As I explained [in another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302632/is-users-reputation-one-of-criteria-for-keeping-their-votes-after-account-delet), it's just correlative. Generally speaking, higher reputation users have more votes and are less likely to be involved in voting fraud, so their votes are more likely to be kept. A lower reputation user having a very high number of votes is more likely to be doing some inappropriate with those votes, so it's much less likely that a low reputation user's votes will be preserved. On the opposite hand, a high-rep user's votes *could* be destroyed (it's happened before), but that's much less common.

Ultimately, any time a user has cast enough votes to pass our thresholds, their profile will be held up for manual review by staff. But we can't explain all of the fine details of deletion and vote retention in a help center article meant to provide a basic overview of how things work.