# When a user account is deleted, what decides when to preserve and remove the votes of the user?

Tags: support, voting, user-accounts

When a user account is removed (either by request or due to violating the network's terms of service), the users of the site lose or gain some reputation because their votes are also removed along with their account details.

From relevant [help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed),

> This message means that a user who voted for one of your posts had their account deleted (either by request or due to violating the network's terms of service). As a result, all of their votes were removed, and the reputation you gained or lost from them was undone. The resultant reputation change could be any amount; it could even be a reputation gain if enough of the removed votes were downvotes. All the reputation changes from a single user's deletion are rolled into a single event in the reputation page labelled "User was removed".

But I noticed that when a user account was deleted on one of the sites I participated, I didn't gain or lose any reputation. I know that he has upvoted my answers posts from his comments and messages in the chat rooms.

So, I came to know that votes are not removed in all the cases.

On what basis it is decided when to remove the votes and when to preserve? Does the criteria differ for deletion by the request of users?

Shog9 in an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/357396) to there are certain thresholds when the user is involved in voting fraud but my question is about accounts deleted by request also.

Comment: @Yaron The questions are entirely different. Shog9 gave an answer there for user deletion when there is against the rules but it is unclear to me what are those thresholds mentioned in the answer.  My question also covers deletion by request also.

Comment: No, it's the same. Shog explains exactly what you asked. The voting fraud cause the votes to be discarded, even if otherwise (according to thresholds) they would have been preserved.

Comment: @Shadow The questions are different. It is an FR, mine is a support.  I thought questions make questions duplicate. The answer says that votes are discarded during voting fraud. Is it different for self deletions? Are the votes preserved or deleted? I couldn't understand.

Comment: No no. The answer says the votes are always kept when the threshold is met, **unless there is voting fraud involved**. At least that's how I read it. If you think it's not clear, try posting comment and ask Shog to clarify. As fo the general case, once a feature is done, support question asking the same thing becomes duplicate since the feature request has the answer already.