# The threshold for manual review of user deletion should be higher

Tags: feature-request, deleted-accounts

> Due to your number of votes and/or your reputation, this deletion requires final approval from a developer before it is completed

That's on the basis of:

- 916 upvotes
- 730 downvotes (excluding the downvotes on deleted posts, which don't matter anyway).
- 3,347 reputation

None of this looks like the sort of activity that would create a major disturbance  if the votes were discarded (which was the [motivation for having this review process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608)). The low threshold for manual review results in more busywork for employees, who surely have better things to do:

> [image: deletion]

I propose to recalibrate the algorithm so that **only upvotes are considered**, and have a higher threshold for them than the current one. If someone got, say, 20 downvotes which are discarded with user deletion, they are not going to be  upset by seeing +40 (as opposed to seeing -200 with the loss of 20 upvotes).

Comment: Oh right, I knew there was something I forgot to do Friday... BTW: the distribution of votes also matters. If those 916 upvotes cluster around a relatively small number of authors, they'll notice it a lot more readily than if it were 1 vote / author.

Comment: All the more reason to delete the votes if they are abnormally concentrated.

Comment: The "abnormally" bit is why they wait for me in a queue (and now why I wait for an internal tool to become unborked)

Answer (score 7):

It's not just about reputation losses -- though, on smaller sites, what you're describing could make a big difference!  It's about the votes.  Where there are lots of votes there is the potential for voting fraud.  Voting fraud harms the site by undermining community ranking of answers.  It's also a check on malicious deletions -- if somebody compromises your account and can immediately delete it, you're going to be unhappy because account restoration is nigh unto impossible.  (In extraordinary circumstances, *partial* restoration is possible.)

For both of these reasons, it's worth having a human review these deletions.  *Usually* the delay doesn't really affect anything; if you've decided to walk away from a site, why do you care if the wrap-up takes another day or two?  You're done -- go ahead and leave.

If the problem is that, having decided to leave one site only, you're aggravated by new inbox/achievements notifications from that site, you could instead make a feature request to suppress topbar notifications from accounts in the deletion queue.

Comment: "you could instead make a feature request to suppress notifications from accounts in the deletion queue" It's worth noting that these don't just exist to try to give people an oppertunity to reconsider a possibly hasty decision, but almost more importantly to prevent abuse in the event an account is compromised.  You don't want someone being able to easily delete your account and prevent you from getting notifications that it's happening if they guess your password or something like that.

Comment: @Servy I meant the usual notifications (votes, comments, etc).  Nothing in that activity would tell you that your account is pending deletion.  Account deletions generate email, assuming you gave a valid email address.  Good point about wanting to delay in case of compromise; I'll edit that in.