# How many reputation points exactly should a deleted user have to prevent vote invalidation?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-accounts

Yes, I know, we have this question: [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/260198)

But it's not clear.

Old SOru discussion: [Когда аккаунт удаляется с сохранением голосов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7429/15479). A user with **high reputation score** was deleted, and all their votes were invalidated.

Recently [our member with 15k+ reputation](https://web.archive.org/web/20180730150957/https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/207618/aid) was deleted and his votes were invalidated. So, did Stack Exchange staff decide, that 15k is not a **high reputation score**? Or something else?

How many reputation points exactly should a deleted user have to prevent vote invalidation?

Answer (score 9):

The reputation **does not matter**; it's all about [the (up)votes they've cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/295232).

Of course, high reputation users are likely to have been active for a longer period and thus cast more votes. But there's not a threshold like you're asking for.

Another recent case was [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10927/116151) where the user with the most reputation on the site was deleted, and all their votes were invalidated.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. So, another way, what's criteria for those decisions if, in general, reputation doesn't count? 'cause I'm sure that this user wasn't involved in voting fraud or something like this.

Comment: Those can be found in the linked answer. There are no *specific* criteria, it seems that's on purpose to prevent people from taking advantage of them.

Comment: It all depends on the mood of the reviewer. Got it.

Comment: So, casting >50 upvotes isn't enough for these "low" thresholds? I'm skeptical. (And your linked example is very clearly anything but "oh thousands of votes isn't enough to hit the threshold".)

Comment: Quoting Shog: "If, during review, it becomes apparent that the user is or ever was involved in voting fraud, the votes are discarded as they would normally be." I don't know if this is the case here.