# How can the Community user earn the "Warm Welcome" hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, community-user

The Community user **downvotes on spam/ evil posts**, but to earn the "Warm Welcome" hat, it needs to ...  (not revealing the secret,  those who earned will know).

[image][image]

The Community User has earned the "Warm Welcome" hat in 10 sites. How can the Community User earn this hat, when it doesn't

> Shhh! secret!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Community user doesn't take this action directly (since, you know, it's not a real user).

When a user account is deleted, in some rare cases, all of its <REDACTED> are transferred to the Community user. Thus, the Community user has effectively performed the <REDACTED> task, as required to earn the Warm Welcome hat.

Comment: Thank you! Till now I thought they'll go away as  users get deleted in all cases.

Comment: See the "It also" bullet points from [the answer in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739).

Comment: I wonder how such a rare occurrence(as you put it) occurred during the limited hat period.

Comment: Rare occurrences occur all the time on a site as large as Stack Overflow, @TheMaster.

Comment: More specifically, @TheMaster, see [this Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed) for an explanation of when and why a deleted account's upvotes are transferred to Community. Basically, it's a matter of discretion when a user account with a large number of votes is deleted. See also Meta discussions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328646, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470

Comment: Is there a record of such actions? Is that record accessible by mods? I'm asking because, from my perspective, it is just speculation at this point. If it is accessible by mods, Does your audit show these <REDACTED> comments?

Comment: Yes, there is a record of how an account is deleted. That information is accessible to moderators. But I'm somewhat confused by your comment. Are you talking about "<REDACTED>" as it appears in *this* answer? That was only because, at the time this question was asked, Winter Bash was going on, and the hat's trigger was a secret. I did not want to disclose the trigger in this answer (in other posts, it was protected by spoiler markdown).