# Is there a limit for "user was deleted" being propagated as reputation being removed?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-accounts

Today I saw the following:

[image: Reputation being lost due to user removal]

Clearly the removed user has voted a tremendous number of times on politics and it is plausible that this is related to voting irregularity.

However, I remember that somewhere I have read that for some specific cases (users with lot of activity / votes), their removal does not trigger this and I am wondering if an algorithm deals with this or not.

**Question:** Is there a limit for "user was deleted" being propagated as reputation being removed?

Comment: Apparently there's no such limit.

Comment: [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) details the exact cases when a user's votes may be preserved. Specifically, if a user who would potentially have their votes preserved is determined to have engaged in voting fraud, their votes are still invalidated anyway.